# Hide Broadcast Upload Extension in Control Center

Tags: ios, swift, broadcast, replaykit

I have implemented the Broadcast Upload Extension in my app.

My requirement is that the user must start it only within the app, but right now there is an entry in the recorder button in Control Center that lets the user also start it from there.

My question is: how can I remove that entry in Control Center so the only way to start the Upload Extension is via my container app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't hide recorder button from Control Center, but you can check your application state when user start recording from Control center with Broadcaster UI Extension, if you need any action before start recording you can inform user with Broadcaster UI extension.